# How do I retain a formula but keep the cells empty until triggering data is input?

Tags: excel-2010

I'm new to Excel, so please be patient and kind.

In cell G3, I have a triggering date entered (example: 10/02/2018).  In cell H3, I have entered the formula, G3+15, with the result being 10/17/2018.  The formula in cell I3 is H3+15, with the result being 11/01/2018.  This continues along the row until I reach 90 days from the triggering date of 10/02/2018.

When I copied the formula down the columns, the cells read across the row as 01/15/1900, 01/30/1900, etc.

How do I keep the formula set behind the scenes, so to speak, but keep the cells empty of data until the triggering date is entered in column G?

The triggering date will be entered as needed based upon specific events.

Thank you for reading and your suggestions.

Dana

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple `IF` statement. In H3 use the formula:
`=IF(G3="","",G3+15)`

This formula can then be dragged to the right/copied to the right to give you the number of columns you need.

The way this works is by validating the contents of `G3`. It is asking "Is cell `G3` empty, if so, then return nothing; if not, do the math."